# Display PHP variable from a different page

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<div style="width:100%; position:fixed; z-index:999; top:0; left:0; padding:10px; background-color:#666666; height:50px;">
<h3><button id="inbox_button" >Inbox <?php echo $messages_num; ?></button></h3>
<div id="inbox_div" style="background-color:#eeeeee; width:350px; height:400px; overflow-y:scroll; display:none; margin-top:20px; padding:0px;">
<?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/includes/menu_messages.php'; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

i am using require_once to include a php file. the file (`menu_messages.php`) has the PHP variable `$messages_num;` in, how can i echo this on the `Inbox button` - i have `echoed` it above but its not displaying

Comment: You're echoing it _before_ including the file that contains it?

Comment: i know, im not sure what i can do to make it work

Comment: You can not use a variable before it is declared, this is very simple and basic, you should learn php

Comment: but if i declare the require before i echo the variable, it will show my required file in the wrong place

Comment: @charliejsford that makes no sense. Read some basic tutorials

Comment: it does make sense. i am requiring the file within a DIV, if i move the require it will display the code in the required file in the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

you need to include the other php file before you can call any variables stored within it.

Answer (score 0):

You should require the file first, the output is blank because the file holding the variable isn't loaded yet.